# Getting File list from Adobe Media Server 5

Tags: android, flash-media-server

I have started working on a VOD app for Android. I am using the Adobe Media Server 5 for my streaming solution.
I have been able to figure out how to configure the server to put files in the correct location and things like that.

Right now my problem is that I want to display a list of all available media files on the AMS in my android application so that the user can go ahead and select the appropriate file for playing back.

Do i need to create a .m3u8 kind of manifest for all the files that are available and then access that to get a complete listing of all the files or is there some other way to achieve what i am looking for?